# Having trouble debugging error: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter"

Tags: c#

Not too great with methods as I find them confusing. I have error CS7036, There is no argument given that corresponds to a required formal parameter.

From what I am reading on other threads, this error means my parameters are empty, but when I look at my code, its not.  Unless I'm messing something up that I'm not aware of.  Any help is appreciated, I commented on the  line I get the error on.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (new Program()).run();
    }

    void run()
    {
        double dailyRate = double.Parse("Enter your daily rate: ");
        int noOfDays = int.Parse("Enter the number of days: ");
        writeFee(calculateFee(dailyRate, noOfDays)); //EROR ON THIS LINE
    }

    private void writeFee(double p, int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The consultant's fee is:  {0}", p * 1.1);
    }

    private double calculateFee(double dailyRate, int noOfDays)
    {
        return dailyRate * noOfDays;
    }

    private double readInt(string p)
    {
        Console.Write(p);
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        return int.Parse(line);
    }

    private double readDouble(int p)
    {
        Console.Write(p);
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        return double.Parse(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: writeFee has two parameters, one of them unused, but you are passing only one. Change it to private void writeFee(double p)

Comment: So that line of code should be: 

writeFee(double p, calculateFee(dailyRate, noOfDays));

?

Comment: No, I proposed to change the definition of writeFee from "private void writeFee(double p, int n)" to "private void writeFee(double p)"

Comment: Oooooo. Ok I see what you mean now.  That fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `writeFee` takes two parameters. You are only passing in one. Remove the `int n` as this is not used. You could also do something like this:

```
 private void WriteFee(double p, int n)
 {
      Console.WriteLine($"The consultant's fee is:  {0}", p * n); //$ marks for string interpolation
 }
```

Where you call the method

```
WriteFee(CalculateFee(dailyRate, noOfDays), 1.1);
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, thank you for the help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Please upvote or accept the answer as this indicates the solution to your problem.